# FileNotFound while downloading directories on Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have my Flask application hosted on a VPS server. Within the server, there are directories containing subdirectories, and further within them, there are directories containing image files. The task is to provide users with the ability to download these folders from the website.

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory
from werkzeug.security import safe_join 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    folder_path = '/home/images/image'
    items = list_directory(folder_path)
    return render_template('index.html', items=items)

@app.route('/explore/<path:subpath>')
def explore(subpath):
    folder_path = safe_join('/home/images/image', subpath) 
    items = list_directory(folder_path)
    return render_template('index.html', items=items)

@app.route('/download/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    folder_path = '/home/images/image'
    return send_from_directory(folder_path, filename, as_attachment=True)

def list_directory(directory):
    result = []
    for item in sorted(os.listdir(directory), key=lambda x: int(x)):
        item_path = os.path.join(directory, item)
        item_type = 'dir' if os.path.isdir(item_path) else 'file'
        result.append({'name': item, 'type': item_type})
    return result
```

This is my HTML-template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>File Explorer</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>File Explorer</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for item in items %}
        <li>
            {% if item.type == 'dir' %}
             <a href="{{ url_for('explore', subpath=item.name) }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
            {% else %}
             {{ item.name }}
            <a href="{{ url_for('download_file', filename=item.name) }}" download>Скачать</a>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

When Im trying to download folder from the server exception raises:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. What's wrong here?

Have no ideas at all :(

Comment: What does "download" in `<a href="{{ url_for('download_file', filename=item.name) }}" download>Скачать</a>` do?